# Getting the object reference must be set to an instance of an object in Generic Handler

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am trying to read some image data from my sql database, i have it writing; all i need to do is get it reading. But i am getting the error stated in the question on line 18? Can somone please help me.

Here is the code:

http://codepad.org/d3Yd702T

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a connection string named `RevisionConnectionString` in your web.config file?

In your web.config file, add the following in the `<configuration>` section:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="RevisionConnectionString" connectionString="whatever it should be for you;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: No i dont, should there be one? The tutorial i was following didnt really give much of a description

Answer (score 1):

Property `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` gets the `ConnectionStringsSection` data for the current application's default configuration.

A `ConnectionStringsSection` object contains the contents of the configuration file's connectionStrings section.

And configuration file is your `web.config`, which means that in it you should have section where is stated conn string as a relation to data source.

So, first check is there a connection string, and if is, check is name written properly.

Answer (score 0):

Line 18 shows this:

```
string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RevisionConnectionString"].ToString();
```

Which can only mean that you don't have a ConnectionString with key `RevisionConnectionString`